# React Native Plugin in Ionic application

Tags: react-native

1. Created React Native application
2. Published as library in npm
3. Trying to use same library in Ionic, get parser error.

Need what configuration to be included to make react native plugin for cordova /ionic

Thanks

[image]

Comment: can you please share the plugin.xml

Comment: <platform name="android">
    <!-- your configuration elements, references, source files, etc... -->

    <framework src="src/android/yourFile.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />

    <resource-file src="yourDirContainingYourAAR/foo.aar" target="libs/foo.aar" />
</platform>